# Looking for a record that contains an acrostic (hidden word in a poem) using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Here is my scenario.  I have a database that has varchar(max) field. In one record in the database, this field contains a couple of paragraphs worth of sentences. The guy who entered this particular record did a hidden word thing where the first letter of each sentence in a line forms a word. Like:

```
My mother told me that
I am the best artist she has seen.
Can you believe it?
Everyone else does.
```

This results in the word MICE.
Using SQL to query the database, how can I find this record?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are the line breaks also  saved in the database with the text?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, Mysql, Postgres, Oracle, etc..)?

Comment: Do you have a table of possible words?

Comment: Is this just an intellectual exercise? SQL really isn't the best tool for this job.

Comment: This _CAN_ be done in SQL. You'd want to create a function that will split the string on your delimiter (and you'll **HAVE** to have a delimiter), select your character and concat or stuff it back into your return variable to make your hidden string. It would depend on what type of SQL you are using and what features are available in your language. However, it would likely be horribly inefficient, and I agree that this isn't really a job for SQL.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using SQL Server.  Not an intellectual exercise.  But a curiosity.  A coworker created a record and saved it to the database.  Had some funny stuff in it and he said i'd never find it.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here'a one way to do it in Oracle using Common Table Expressions (CTE's).  tbl_orig below simply sets up test data.  This represents your source data with a multi-line column.

tbl_first contains a row number column and a column for the first character of each row of the multi-line column.  It uses the connect-by clause to loop through each line, setting the row number (used to assemble the letters later)  and grabbing the first character following the start of the line anchor or where it follows a new-line.

Then the final query uses listagg() to convert the rows into one line. If your database is not Oracle, perhaps you can find the steps involved useful to break down the problem in order to apply the logic to your environment.  Remember to post your solution when you figure it out!

```
SQL> with tbl_orig(str) as (
     select 'My mother told me that
   I am the best artist she has seen.
   Can you believe it?
   Everyone else does.' from dual
   ),
   tbl_first(rn, ltr) as (
     select level rn, regexp_substr(str, '(^|\\r)(.)', 1, level, 'm', 2) ltr
     from tbl_orig
     connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '\r')+1
   )
   SELECT LISTAGG(ltr)
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn) secret_word
   FROM tbl_first;

SECRET_WORD
-----------------------------------------------
MICE
```

EDIT: Simplified the query.  This can actually be done in one statement.  As before, tbl_orig is just the original data.  The select takes the first letter of each line and combines them as it loops through the lines of the column.  No need for a separate CTE.

ALSO '\r' seems to cause issues with blank lines.  Changed to CHR(10)'s and now it works.  Hmmm. Listagg() ignores NULLs.

```
SQL> with tbl_orig(str) as (
     select 'My mother told me that
   I am the best artist she has seen.

   Can you believe it?
   Everyone else does.

   Alas' from dual
   )
   SELECT LISTAGG(regexp_substr(str, '(^|'||CHR(10)'||)(.)', 1, level, 'm', 2))
   WITHIN GROUP (order by rownum) secret_word
   FROM tbl_orig
   connect by level <= regexp_count(str, CHR(10))+1;

SECRET_WORD
-----------
MICEA

SQL>
```

Comment: Eliminated the intermediate CTE